# Scope and Variable Resolution in Ruby Blocks

Tags: ruby, file, variables, scope

There is something that I am missing in the following code.

```
hostnames =  []
ip_addrs  =  []
hw_addrs  =  []

File.open("/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf", "r").each_line do |line|

  unless line.match('#')                        # Make sure the line is not commented
    if line.match("host-name")
        hostname = line.scan(/"([^"]*)"/)       # extract the Hostname
    elsif line.match("fixed-address")
        ip_addr = line.scan(/(\S*);/)           # Extract IP addr
    elsif line.match("ethernet")
      hw_addr = line.scan(/(\S*);/)             # Extract the HW address
    end
  end

  hostnames + hostname.to_a if hostname         # Protect against `nil' values
  ip_addrs  + ip_addr.to_a  if ip_addr          #  Same
  hw_addrs  + hw_addr.to_a  if hw_addr          #  Same

end

puts hostnames.inspect                          # Should be a list of hostnames...
```

This should populate the arrays with the values found in the `dhcpd.conf` file.
If I print the values inside the `File.open.each_line` block then I get the complete list to STDOUT. When I try to get the values outside of the block I get empty arrays.

I think that the block generates a copy of my variables and works on those, but they don't get passed back out of the block. I'm not sure how the internals work, just a guess.

Comment: You didn't add it to the hostnames array. Try hostnames << hostname.to_a

Comment: Is this an exact copy of your code? The three statements before the last `end` don't make sense. Were those supposed to be assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add something to an array you need to use the proper operator:

```
hostnames += hostname.to_a if hostname
```

What you're doing is creating a temporary result and discarding it: `a + b` is not a permanent modification, but `a = a + b` is, where the short-hand is `a += b`.

Generally you use `<<` to add single elements to an array, it avoids creating a new array and just appends to the existing one. For example:

```
hostnames << hostname if hostname
```

That's generally sufficient. Casting everything to arrays just to concatenate them is wasteful unless you are actually appending several values at once.

Comment: Right, as soon as I read this I remembered. Thanks. I knew I was missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Change `hostnames + hostname.to_a` to `hostnames << hostname.to_a`

In the current version of your code, you don't actually add the `hostname` to the `hostnames` array. `<<` pushes the `hostname` element to `hostnames`